# Why isn't my footer displayed in the bottom ? what is wrong with this CSS?

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

So I'd like my footer to adjust and stay on the bottom of the page no matter the height of the content which is dynamic

Below is the CSS for the body, wrapper and footer .. the footer doesn't not stay in the bottom when the content is too long and gets display in the middle of the page when you have to scroll

```
body, html{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#FFFFFF;
}

#wrapper{
 position:relative;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 width:100%;
 padding:0px;
 min-height:100%;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}

#footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
left:150px;
width:1600px;
height:500px;
background:blue;
}
```

...

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"></div>
     <div id="logo"><img src="images/u176.png" class="logo_pic" style="outline: none;"></div>
       <div id="search_bar"><input type="text" name="search_bar" class="search" /></div>
          <div id="search_icon"><img src="images/u205.png" width="28px" height="28px" /></div>
            <div id="become_a_chef"><span id="become_title">Become </span></div>
              <div id="login">Log in</div>
                <div id="sign_up">Sign up</div>
                 <div id="tap-container"><img id="tap-pic" class="food_container_pic" src="images/today_menu/u35.png" /></div>
                 <div id="tap-content"></div>
                     <div class="column1">
                       <div class="tap-links">Become a member</div>
                       <div class="tap-links">Sign up</div>
                       <div class="tap-links">Log in</div>
                       <div class="tap-links">Home</div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="column2">
                       <div class="tap-links">Search</div>
                       <div class="tap-links">Download the App</div>
                       <div class="tap-links">How it works</div>
                       <div class="tap-links">Help</div>
                     </div>
                  <div id="chef-rating-responsive">
                    <div class="subinfo_container3"><img class="food_container_pic" src="images/fusion/u1837.jpg" /></div>
                    <div class="subinfo_container4">A</div>
                    <div class="subinfo_container5">Open Now</div>
                    <div class="subinfo_container6">More...</div>
                  </div>
                   <div id="cover_picture_container"><img class="food_container_pic" src="images/u4.jpg" /></div>
                    <div id="profile_picture_container"><img  id="profile_picture" class="img" src="<?php echo $picture;?>"></div>
                      <div id="chef_description_container">
                          <div id="kitchen_name"><span id="kitchen_title"><?php echo $name;?></span></div>
                            <div id="chef_description_summary"><?php echo description;?></div>
                            <div id="schedule_info_container">
                                <div class="subinfo_container">
                                   <img id="chef_rating" src="images/fusion/u1837.jpg" width="186px" height="35px">
                                   <span id="number_reviews">64 reviews</span>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="subinfo_container"><span id="open_now">Open Now</span></div>
                                   <div class="subinfo_container"><span id="chef_location">Chef Location</span></div>
                                    <div class="subinfo_container2"><span id="letter_grade">A</span><span id="chef_grade">since Nov.2016</span></div>
                                     <div class="subinfo_container2">
                                        <div id="clock"><img id="u1341_img" src="images/u1341.png" class="full" ></div>
                                        <span id="schedule_hours"></span>
                                    </div>
                                     <div class="subinfo_container2"><span id="chef_contact">Chef contact</span></div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
            <div  class="today_menu">
               <div class="space"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                 <div class="company_footer">
                    <div class="title">Company</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">About</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">Careers</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">Press</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">Blog</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">About</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">Help</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">Policies</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">Disaster</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">Terms & Privacy</div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="discover_footer">
                   <div class="title">Discover</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">Trust & Safety</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">Invite friends</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">Gift card</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">pricks</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">Mobile</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">Events support</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">Travel</div>
                    <div class="column_content_footer">Nearby</div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="kitchening_footer">
                       <div class="title"></div>
                       <div class="column_content_footer"></div>
                       <div class="column_content_footer">Serving</div>
                       <div class="column_content_footer">Responsible</
                     </div>
                     <div class="social_media_buttons">Hey</div>
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: Just a footer that stays at the very bottom page of the page no matter how long the content is. Mine stays at the bottom when there is no overflow, when you dont have to scroll the page , but when the content gets longer, there's space below the footer.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#footer {
  z-index: 50;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div id="footer">
</div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly fine for me (tweaked it a little bit). I'd advice you not to use fixed widths like `1600px`, but to work with percentages and max-widths. Hope this helps

Comment: Edited the snippet. Check if it solves your problem.

Comment: My code works just perfect on my other site but on this new one , nope. weird .. still trying to see .. It's basically the wrapper not adjusting well to the height of the content ...so the footer will not be at bottom:0px;

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/89gdtvze/3/ I tested it out with this fiddle with test content. It works for me here (if we understand each other right). Inject as many <br> tags as you want, the footer stays at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for trying but your footer hides the content, it shouldn't . it should just readjust to the height of the content

Comment: I do not understand. Don't you want to have a fixed footer that is constantly displayed above the content for `400px`? Also the content is not completly hidden, it is just pushed down to the bottom (scroll) due to the padding of the wrapper element which has the same size as the footer.

Comment: Check out my answer Arnold, thanks to your clarification this should be it.

Comment: @ArnoldStoba posted html structure above

Answer (score 0):

If your footer has a fixed height you could do something like this:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.force-min-height {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  background: grey;
}

.content {
  /* padding being the same as footer height */
  padding-bottom: 4em;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 4em;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="force-min-height">
   <div class="header">Header</div>
   <div class="content">
      line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line
   </div>
   <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because editing your original comment was too easy :P

Comment: I am new to this and just trying out things... (like: will I loose points if i delete an answer that received an upvote ;-)